# Disable driver-less fingerprint reader?

Tags: usb, power-management, battery, lsusb

Currently running ubuntu 18.04.1, I have a laptop with a unsupported fingerprint reader:

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c7a:0570 LighTuning Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5c5 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg | grep "1c7a" :

```
usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1c7a, idProduct=0570
```

powetop is saying that the device is 100% usage while lsusb -v is showing that it can draw up to 100mA.

Is there any harm in leaving a driver-less device enabled or is there any way to cut power to it in order to save power?

Thanks!

Comment: All else failing, chances are you should be able to disable it in your BIOS setup. In that case the OS won't see the device at all.

Comment: It was the first thing i tired, unfortunately acer does not include that option in their BIOS on the acer swift 3, thanks for the suggestion!